# Validating a set of form fields combined, instead of just one field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

**Case**

I have a Symfony2 form with a builder as you'd expect. Example:

```
$builder->add('home_team', 'choice', [$options])
    ->add('away_team', 'choice', [$more_options])
    ->add('timestamp', 'datetime_picker', [$usual_stuff]);
```

Now, I have some single-field validations, like NotNull etc, but I need this one validator that ensures me against near-duplicate entries.

Specifically, I want to ensure that no one saves a row where there is an existing `home_team`, `away_team`, as well as a same-day `timestamp`.

**Question**

When I make a `UniqueMatchValidator` class, with a `validate()` function, how do I apply this validator to the entire form, rather than just to a field?

**Clarification**

I'm familiar with applying validators to single fields, but applying to a set of fields, or indeed an entire form, is what I'm wondering about.

**My thoughts**

I was thinking I could apply the validator to a single field, but then I need to know the values of the other ones. Would this be a possible solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the best solution, but what I would do is that  I'll do that check inside my form valid function and if it's not valid [ this combo already exists, I'll throw an error]